# Linux commandline to share an EC2 snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-ec2, snapshot

I would like to setup a batch process as follows on Amazon AWS:

1. take snapshot of volumes tagged "must_backup"
2. share those snapshots with account B
3. make a copy of those snapshots within account B

the purpose of this is to protect the backups in case the first Amazon AWS account gets compromised.

I know how to automate steps 1 & 3, however I cannot find a commandline example on how to perform step 2.
The official documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modifying-snapshot-permissions.html
does not provide any sample and does not clearly state how to specify the target account on the commandline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've double checked the previous solution and it's not ok. Basically "sharing" a snapshot means allowing other accounts to create a volume from that snapshot.

This implies adding a value to the "createVolumePermission" attribute

```
aws ec2 modify-snapshot-attribute --snapshot-id snap-<id> --user-ids <user-id-without-hypens> --attribute createVolumePermission --operation add
```

the operation might take some time (minutes?) after that you'll be able to query the attribute this way:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshot-attribute --snapshot-id snap-<id> --attribute createVolumePermission
```

PS: for the purposes mentioned in the question this is probably not enough since the 'destination' account will not be able to see any of the tags from the source account, thus it will be impossible to perform a correct backup if the source account shares multiple snapshots with the same size

Answer (score 0):

Example Commands for aws cli: copy ec2 snapshot

`aws ec2 modify-snapshot-attribute --snapshot-id snap-1234567890 --user-ids other-amazon-account-id`

Comment: this is not correct, see the answer below where I made some tests to work out how to do it